# De-interleave audio channels using SIMD instructions

Tags: audio, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm implementing a sound mixer, it works well without SIMD instructions, but having a hard time figuring out how to extract my sound data into separate channels.

My data comes in an interleaved format: L0R0 L1R1 L2R2 L3R3...
I load them into a __m128i in the same format, so I have 4 sample in the register.

I'd like them to be in separate channels: L0L1L2L3 R0R1R2R3. This is the part that I'm missing.

So the input is: 8 x i16 (4xi32 interleaved)
I would like the output as left = 4 x f32 and right = 4 x f32, then do the mixing.

After the mixing, I can interleave the channels and i get L0R0 L1R1 L2R2...:

```
__m128 *src0 = mixed_channel0;
__m128 *src1 = mixed_channel1;
__m128 *dest = (__m128i *)buffer;

for (u32 sample_index = 0; sample_index < sample_chunk_count; ++sample_index)
{
    __m128 s0 = _mm_load_ps((f32 *)src0++);
    __m128 s1 = _mm_load_ps((f32 *)src1++);

    __m128i l = _mm_cvtps_epi32(s0);
    __m128i r = _mm_cvtps_epi32(s1);

    __m128i lr0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(l, r);
    __m128i lr1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(l, r);

    *dest++ = _mm_packs_epi32(lr0, lr1);
}
```

Basically I need to do the opposite:

```
__m128i input = [L0R0, L1R1, L2R2, L3R3] packed pairs of 16bit ints
// magic happens, then
__m128 left = [L0, L1, L2, L3] packed 32bit floats
__m128 right = [R0, R1, R2, R3] packed 32bit floats
```

Even if I mask out the low/high order i16-s, then how can i convert them to  f32-s? After masking out i would get:

```
__m128i right = [xx, R0, xx, R1, xx, R2, xx, R3]
__m128i left = [L0, xx, L1, xx, L2, xx, L3, xx]
```

If I could convert them to 4 x i32-s then it would be easy to convert them to f32-s with _mm_cvtepi32_ps and i would be done.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your best bet for converting the low/high `i16`s is with bit-shifts.  `high_halves = _mm_srai_epi32(packed, 16);`.  Since your values are signed, you probably need to sign-extend the low halves by left-shifting and then using an arithmetic right shift.  I can't think of a better way ATM, but this does seem kind of clunky.

Comment: Some SIMD instruction sets (like ARM NEON / ARMv8) have more two-input or two-output instructions, and I think could do this unpack with a single instruction.  (Maybe unzip, IIRC).  So it's important to say specifically with Intel SSE, not just any SIMD.

Comment: Can you require [SSE3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/09/11/directxmath-sse3-and-ssse3/)? While it's not 'required' the way [SSE/SSE2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/09/11/directxmath-sse-sse2-and-arm-neon/) is for modern PCs, it's very common (for Steam gamers it's 91%). ``_mm_moveldup_ps`` and ``_mm_movehdup_ps`` are quite useful.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: What are you picturing with duplicating the even or odd elements with SSE3?  The OP's desired output doesn't need to move any data outside of the 32-bit elements they started in.  At first I was picturing a use for `shufps` to combine data from two vectors, but then I read more carefully, and the middle code block is the one that shows the input and desired outputs.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you, the `_mm_srai_epi32` gives me the left channel values; `_mm_slli_epi32` 16 then `_mm_srai_epi32` 16 gives me the right channel values, converting them to `f32`-s is straight forward. I would accept your comment as an answer if i could, or maybe i will post the code when i'm home with tests that i made for it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Mask and shift to go from pairs of 16-bit samples 32-bit samples.

```
// clunky calling convention, but should inline ok.
__m128 unpack_leftright_16bit_channels(__m128i input, __m128 &right_retval) {
    // input = [L0R0, L1R1, L2R2, L3R3] packed pairs of 16bit ints
    // the one we're calling "right" is the low half of 0xLLLLRRRR
    __m128i sign_extended_left  = _mm_srai_epi32(input, 16);

    //__m128i high_right = _mm_slli_epi32(input, 16);
    //__m128i sign_extended_right = _mm_srai_epi32(high_right, 16);
    __m128i sign_extended_right = _mm_madd_epi16(input, _mm_set1_epi32(0x00000001));

    right_retval = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(sign_extended_right);
    //__m128 right = [R0, R1, R2, R3] packed 32bit floats
    
    __m128 left  = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(sign_extended_left);
    //__m128 left = [L0, L1, L2, L3] packed 32bit floats
    return left;
}
```

This [compiles to what you'd expect with gcc5.3](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:%27-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dnehalem%27,source:%27%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0A//+clunky+calling+convention,+but+should+inline+ok.%0A__m128+unpack_leftright(__m128i+input,+__m128+%26right_retval)+%7B%0A++++//++++__m128i+input+%3D+%5BL0R0,+L1R1,+L2R2,+L3R3%5D+packed+pairs+of+16bit+ints%0A++++__m128i+sign_extended_left++%3D+_mm_srai_epi32(input,+16)%3B%0A++++__m128i+high_right+%3D+_mm_slli_epi32(input,+16)%3B%0A++++__m128i+sign_extended_right+%3D+_mm_srai_epi32(high_right,+16)%3B%0A%0A++++right_retval+%3D+_mm_cvtepi32_ps(sign_extended_right)%3B%0A++++//__m128+right+%3D+%5BR0,+R1,+R2,+R3%5D+packed+32bit+floats%0A%0A++++__m128+left++%3D+_mm_cvtepi32_ps(sign_extended_left)%3B%0A++++//__m128+left+%3D+%5BL0,+L1,+L2,+L3%5D+packed+32bit+floats%0A++++return+left%3B%0A%7D%27)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3), or clang3.7.  (Naming convention: The "right" output is the one with lower address, so it's on the right if you're writing your vector data such that right shifts go toward the right, high element first.  This might not be the right audio channel.)

**Another option for sign-extending the low 16-bit half of each 32-bit chunk is `_mm_madd_epi16(input, _mm_set1_epi32(0x00000001))`** to do a widening signed multiply ([`pmaddwd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaddwd)) by `1` for the low halves, `0` for the high halves.  Higher latency but only a single uop.  For the high half, one arithmetic right shift is better than `pmaddwd` with `0x00010000`.

Or as @chtz suggests, shift to the left, convert to float and take the extra factor of `0x10000` into account on subsequent operations. If the extra factor can be compensated for later, the high-word can even be just masked by a bitwise AND:

```
  left  = _mm_and_si128(input, _mm_set1_epi32(0xffff0000));
  right = _mm_slli_epi32(input, 16);
// then convert to floats that are pre-scaled by 2^16.
```

It's probably not worth it to do an FP multiply by `1/65536.0f` after conversion; shift + `_mm_madd_epi16` would be cheaper on most CPUs.  (Unfortunately you can't just integer subtract 16 from the exponent field because that breaks for an input of `0`, and making it conditional would cost as more instructions.)

---

The original code I proposed (using 3 shifts) will bottleneck on shift throughput on most microarchitectures (see [Agner Fog's](http://agner.org/optimize/) insn tables and microarch pdf, https://uops.info/, and other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).  It might be worth using SSSE3 `pshufb` to do the logical left-shift, only using actual shift instructions for the arithmetic right shifts that need to leave a copy of the sign bit in the upper half of each 32-bit element.  Without AVX, `pshufb` shuffles in-place, just like `pslld` shifts in-place so it doesn't avoid the extra MOVDQA instruction to make a 2nd copy of the input.

On Skylake, immediate vector shifts run on p0/p1, and so does `cvtdq2ps`.  Using `pshufb` for the left shift would increase throughput to one float output vector per clock, since shuffles run on port 5.

Pre-skylake, immediate vector shifts only run on a single port, e.g. p0 in Haswell.  At least that's not the same port as int->float:  Haswell runs `cvtdq2ps` on p1.  So again, pshufb would increase throughput to one ps vector per clock.

The updated version using `_mm_madd_epi16` does one shift, one integer multiply, and two FP conversions.  Integer multiply competes for the same ports as shifts and FP conversion (all p0/p1) on Skylake, but at least it's only one uop.  Recent Zen (3 and 4 at least) run some of those on different ports.

It seems very wasteful to use an integer multiply just for sign-extension, but it's only 16-bit so hopefully it won't heat up CPUs too much compared to running two shifts. `pmaddwd` is still 1/clock throughput on Alder Lake E-cores (Gracemont), vs. 3/clock for vector shifts like `psrad`.

Comment: Possible alternative for sign-extending the low-word: `((x^0x8000)&0xFFFF)-0x8000` (requires 3uops instead of 2, though). Or actually, shift to the left, convert to float and take the extra factor of `0x10000` into account on subsequent operations. If the extra factor can be compensated for later, the high-word can even be just masked by a bit-and.